# composing form data with HttpClient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to send form data to my webserver from a Windows Phone 8 application. The data contains a file to upload and additional some strings (key=value).

The composing and sending of the file works fine. But how can I add now my strings to the send content?

```
string mServerUrl = @"http://www.myserver/reveiver.asp";
_ImageMemoryStream.Position = 0;
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(CreateFileContent(_ImageMemoryStream, "uploadedphoto.jpg", "image/jpeg"));

HttpClient mHttpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage mResponse = null;
mResponse = await mHttpClient.PostAsync(mServerUrl, content);
string responseBodyAsText = await mResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (mResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    txtError.Text = "OK:" + responseBodyAsText;
}
else
{
    txtError.Text = "ERROR (" + mResponse.StatusCode + "):\n" + mResponse.ReasonPhrase;
}
```

Helper for composing the file:

```
private StreamContent CreateFileContent(Stream stream, string fileName, string contentType)
{
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "\"file\"",
        FileName = "\"" + fileName + "\""
    };
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
    return fileContent;
}
```

Adding my key/value pair in this way doesn´t fit:

```
content.Add("key", "value");
```

I want to add to my form-data some of These pairs ... Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it on my own:

```
content.Add(new StringContent("value_string"), "\"key_string\"");
content.Add(CreateFileContent(mStream, mFilename, "image/jpeg"));
```

this works. Remeber my helper function `CreateFileContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyvaluePairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
KeyValuePair<string, string> keyvalue = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "value");
keyvaluePairs.Add(keyvalue);
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyvaluePairs));
```

Haven't tested this myself (with Multipart), but with `FormUrlEncodedContent` it works fine for me.

Comment: No that doesn´t work for me. Adding this after the image, even the image is not read proper on server and adding before image, the key ans values are not reorgnized by server script.

Comment: I can't comment on your own solution, but good that you found out what the server expects as post values.